# Question about generators and Hom functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

In a given category $\mathcal{C}$ I want to prove the following statement:

- If $U$ es a generator in the category $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if the left-exact functor $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(U,-): \mathcal{C} \to Ab$ is and embedding where $Ab$ is the category of abelian groups.

Where I have the following definitions:

(a)An embedding is  a faithful functor  whichs sends different objects into different objects.\

(b) A generator in $\mathcal{C}$ is an object $U$ in $\mathcal{C}$ which for given two morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ ; $f,g: A \to B$ such that $f \neq g$ then there exist a morphism $u: U \to A$ such $fu \neq gu$.

My idea to prove the statement is that for ($\Rightarrow$) since U is a generator we can easily see that the $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(U,-)$ functor is faithfull since given $f,g$ such $f\neq g$  then $fu \neq gu$ bt how can I prove that the given functor sends different objects into different objects?? the other implication seems direct to prove. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: $\mathcal C$ is a (locally small) abelian category? Otherwise, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U,-):\mathcal C\to\mathrm{Set}$. However, if $X,Y$ are distinct objects of $\mathcal C$ then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U,X)\neq\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U,Y)$ because one generally assume that the Hom-set are disjoint.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}$ is only supossed to be locally small. You are right , that is because category theory axioms. So the implication is just that simple?